# In java, what's the correct syntax for creating/constructing/defining a named variable on the same line as I add it to an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, syntax

I'm populating an arraylist in Java, and I'm wondering if it's possible to cuts some lines by doing the following (except complete):

myArraylist.add(new objectname varname (constructor things));

instead of:

objectname varname = new objectname(constructor things);
myArrayList.add(varname);

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: @Unmitigated am I missing something? It's def. possible

Comment: @Jadefalke What method are you referring to?

Comment: Ah no, I see. You have to get rid of the variable name though.
`arrList.add(new MyClass())`

Comment: Excellent, thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (using a record as an example).  But you won't have any other named instances of the created classes. Only the ones in the List.

```
record SomeClass(int arg1, int arg2){}
List<SomeClass> myArrayList = 
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new SomeClass(1,2), new SomeClass(3,4), ...)));
```

Since `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed size list you will need to pass it to an `ArrayList` constructor to add more elements.